# Monkey Patching a Class Method in Ruby Mail Module

Tags: ruby, email, jruby, monkeypatching

I am currently working on a monkey patch in the JRuby Mail-2.6.0 module. Specifically, I want to patch the `ssl_context` class method. If it helps, this is the full path to the [module](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb#L135).

An issue I am having with the monkey patch is that since I am looking to replace a class method, I am not quite sure what method to use to replace `ssl_context`.

This is what I have for the monkey patch:

```
require 'mail/check_delivery_params'

class << Mail::SMTP
  remove_method :ssl_context
end

module Mail
  class SMTP
        # Allow SSL context to be configured via settings, for Ruby >= 1.9
    # Just returns openssl verify mode for Ruby 1.8.x
    def ssl_context
      openssl_verify_mode = settings[:openssl_verify_mode]

      if openssl_verify_mode.kind_of?(String)
        openssl_verify_mode = "OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_#{openssl_verify_mode.upcase}".constantize
      end

      # context = Net::SMTP.default_ssl_context
      context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new(settings[:ssl_version])
      context.verify_mode = openssl_verify_mode
      context.ca_path = settings[:ca_path] if settings[:ca_path]
      context.ca_file = settings[:ca_file] if settings[:ca_file]
      context
    end
  end
end
```

I am basically just trying to change:

```
context = Net::SMTP.default_ssl_context
```

To:

```
context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new(settings[:ssl_version])
```

I've tried `undef_method`, `remove_class_variable`, and `remove_method`, but kept getting the following type of error:

```
2017-05-17 11:44:03.423 -0700 [ERROR|007d0|main] :: Error starting Application: Undefined method ssl_context for 'Mail::SMTP'
  org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2826:in `undef_method'
  /Users/App/Code/yourtool/lib/helltool/mailer.rb:328:in `singleton class'
  /Users/App/Code/yourtool//lib/helltool/mailer.rb:327:in `<main>'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961:in `require'
```

Curious what I can do to make this work?

Comment: The error is telling you that  `Mail::SMTP` does not have a method called `ssl_context`. This method is an instance method not a class method.

Comment: It looks like instead of using `remove_method`, I simply redefine the method (and adding a `private` on top of the class method), like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33592221/override-a-private-method-in-the-lib-folder-of-a-gem

Comment: This is not a class method that being said your patch should be fine without the first block `class << Mail::SMTP;...` and yes if you want it to be private make it private. Also might be easier to alias the method and make a call to the alias when you want the original functionality.

Comment: @engineersmnky Would you mind writing this as an answer? "Also might be easier to alias the method and make a call to the alias when you want the original functionality."